# Printing out the first index of an array in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, rows

What I am trying to do is print out the first index of an array in JSON format.

With the code:

```
     storeInformation = myStoreInfoTable;
     strResponseOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storeInformation);
```

These are the results:

```
    [
        {
            "distance": 0,
            "descr": "Toronto",
            "address": "1300 Castlefield Avenue",
            "city": "Toronto"
        },
        {
            "distance": 7.1121883392,
            "descr": "Etobicoke - North",
            "address": "Resources Road",
            "city": "Etobicoke"
        }
    ]
```

What I tried to do to get the first index is:

```
    storeInformationRow = dtbStoreInformation.Rows[0];
    strResponseOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storeInformationRow);
```

What I get is:

```
   {
        "RowError": "",
        "RowState": 2,
        "Table": [
            {
                 "distance": 0.0000000000,
                 "descr": "Toronto",
                 "address": "1300 Castlefield Avenue",
                 "city": "Toronto"
            },
            {
                "distance": 7.1121883392,
                "descr": "Etobicoke - North",
                "address": "Resources Road",
                "city": "Etobicoke"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The result I want is just

```
            {
                 "distance": 0.0000000000,
                 "descr": "Toronto",
                 "address": "1300 Castlefield Avenue",
                 "city": "Toronto"
            }
```

Help anybody?

Comment: What are `myStoreInfoTable` and `dtbStoreInformation`? How are they declared and calculated?

Comment: DataTable dtbStoreInformation is just a DataTable
and dtbStoreInformation is a DataTable made from a SQL query

Comment: You need to map the rows out to the appropriate objects. There is no "built-in" coverter for table rows and you shouldn't expect there to be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems to me that the JSON serializer is goofing up because it doesn't know how to correctly serialize a `DataRow`. That's the only difference between the first and second snippet of code.

If you look at [the MSDN documentation for the `DataRow` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) you can see that the `DataRow` has the attributes displayed (`RowError`, `RowState` and `Table`) among many others.

To fix your problem I would suggest one of 2 options:

1. Create a new `DataTable` and add the `DataRow` you want to serialize to it, and call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` on that.
2. Map the columns (distance, descr, address & city) to another class (`Store` or something) and try to serialize that object.  From what I read [in the `JsonConvert` documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) it's possible (the class attributes are mapped correctly onto the JSON object).

Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

you can just use :

var row = dtbStoreInformation.Rows[0];

```
string strResponseOutput = new {
                          distance = row[0].ToString(), 
                          descr= row[1].ToString(), 
                          address = row[2].ToString(),
                          city = row[2].ToString()}.ToJson();
```

don't forget the include of the namespace  `ServiceStack.Text`

You can also create an anonym object

```
var obj = jsonString = new {
                              distance = row[0].ToString(), 
                              descr= row[1].ToString(), 
                              address = row[2].ToString(),
                              city = row[2].ToString()}

strResponseOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: It's not just a matter of just adding the namespace.  He/she would also have to add the project reference, or install the package using NuGet.  Instructions for usage of `ServiceStack.Text` can be found at: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text